# App won't delete. I don't know what they are

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

[image]
I have these three apps that won't delete. They come up as random number and won't go away. I tried rebooting my phone and checking in settings. Even in App Store.

Answer (score 1):

These are apps that may have failed when downloading or didn't remove completely. I've seen it happen from time to time and it is odd that you have three of them. That said the best way to rid yourself of these things is to back up your phone to iTunes (password protect your backup so the backup saves your passwords stored on the phone). Then go into Settings -> General -> reset -> Erase all Contents and Settings.

The phone will do its thing and once it has come back up, plug it back into the computer and restore the phone from the backup you just made.

It's an annoying process to have to go through, but so far have found no other way to do it.